# Create a "hex' layout with an android recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a RecyclerView with items that are laid out in a "hex" formation, similar to this: https://imgur.com/a/LHn0yDT

I tried using a grid layout manager that alternates the span between 2 and 1 like so:

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position % 3 == 0) 2 else 1
    }
}
```

However, what can I do to achieve the necessary spacing? Right now the items look like this

```
**
*
**
*
etc...
```

I'm trying to find a way to center the single item rows, as well as make it vertically offset with the 2 item rows (edited)